# Gausian distributions in the Frequency domain

Tags: gaussian, fourier-analysis

I have read in many texts that the Fourier Transform of a Gaussian is yet another Gaussian, however how does the mean and standard deviation change?

Also if we convolve a Gaussian with itself then we get a wider Gaussian, this is equivalent to the product with the Fourier Transform of the Gaussian with itself. Will this still be a wider Gaussian?

Thanks

Comment: This is in every elementary textbook (AND you can do the computation yourself) so I would not call this a research level question. Voting to close.

Answer (score 1):

The formula for transforming a 0 mean Gaussian says
$F_x\[e^{-ax^2}\](k)=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}e^{-\pi^2k^2/a}$
so the standard deviation certainly changes.  Indeed
the inverse proportionality is an example of the Heisenberg
phenomenon.

Changing the mean of the input by translating its graph
will multiply the output by a phase factor.

A widening self-convolution in one domain corresponds
to a narrowing self-multiplication in the other domain.